# проверка входных данных

Tags: php

Как можно улучшить скрипт с точки зрения безопасности. Хочу фильтровать входные значение. Сейчас скрипт принимает всё подряд, а нужно чтобы только телефона +7и10цифр

```js
<? php

$getFood = $_GET['food'];
$getPhone = $_GET['phone'];

require 'mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$userName = "";
$userPass = "";
$userInfo = '';

$sendTo = '';
$sendToInfo = '!!!';

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail - > isSMTP();

$mail - > SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail - > Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail - > Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail - > Port = 587;
$mail - > SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail - > SMTPAuth = true;
$mail - > Username = $userName;
$mail - > Password = $userPass;
$mail - > setFrom($userName, $userInfo);
$mail - > addReplyTo($userName, $userInfo);
$mail - > CharSet = 'UTF-8';


if (!empty($_GET['phone'])) {

  if (empty($_GET['food'])) {
    $mailSubject = 'Перезвоните клиенту';
    $mailText = "Номер телефона: <b>".$getPhone.
    '</b><br>';
  } else {
    $mailSubject = 'Новый заказ на доставку';
    $mailText = '<h1>Новая заявка на доставку!</h1>Номер телефона: <b>'.$_GET['phone'].
    '</b><br>Блюдо: <b>'.$_GET['food'].
    '</b>';
    echo $mailText;
  }
  $mail - > addAddress($sendTo, $sendToInfo);
  $mail - > Subject = $mailSubject;
  $mail - > msgHTML($mailText, dirname(__FILE__));

  if (!$mail - > send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: ".$mail - > ErrorInfo;
  } else {
    echo "Message sent!";
  }
} else echo "No callback";
```

Comment: лучше бы яваскриптом сразу у пользователя проверить

Comment: @Jean-Claude Даже если проверишь на стороне пользователя, всё равно нужно проверить на сервере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) для проверки регуляркой.

```
if (!empty($_GET['phone']) && preg_match("/\+\d{10}/", $_GET['phone'])) {
    ...
} else echo "No Callback"
```

upd: Чтобы убедиться, что строка включает в себя *только* номер телефона нужно добавить символы начала (^) и конца ($) строки в регулярное выражение:

```
"/^\+\d{10}$/"
```